# Electric generators?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

When a magnet passes through a copper coil and electricity is induced into the coil, is there a magnetic resistance on the magnet as it passes through the coil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the resistance to the magnetic field is called RELUCTANCE. As the magnet moves through a copper coil (consider circular), the change in magnetic field induces current in the coil. Due to the current in the coil, another magnetic field is produced in the opposite direction to the magnet moving through the copper coil. Also, the magnetic strength of both the field are same. But, the directions are exact opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. All metal [resists flux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz%27s_law) to some degree. Aluminum is [especially prone to this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fxC-AEC0ROk), which is the principle behind [eddy current braking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current_brake).